# What is the best way to have a React-generated static (SEO) "public" frontend alongside a CRA "private" app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, gatsby, react-static

I've been using Create-React-App and dig the whole setup, basically I'm looking to keep developing with JSX instead of switching to Gatsby/React-Static's Markdown/etc coding style. Similar question to [this one regarding Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024674/can-i-host-a-gatsby-static-site-alongside-cra). I'm looking to have a search engine optimized static "public" frontend (e.g. product pages, blog, etc.) that is generated by Gatsby or react-static. But I'd also like a typical client-side rendered React app for the "private" section (e.g. sellers can edit their product pages). I know you can set the "homepage" so I was thinking of setting the private section to "example.com/in/" or similar.

Any advice on how to best split this project?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using the GraphQL stuff, Gatsby is predominantly just using React SSR and a custom webpack configuration with Reach Router and some glue to stick it all together.

You can absolutely have a separate Webpack configuration that outputs to your `public` folder and set up your host/deployment to route all of your non-static routes to your application entry.

You can also use Gatsby to generate all of those dynamic pages with juicy client-side fetches, and you basically get free static skeleton entry points for each of your pages like this:

```js
const useMounted = () => {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true)
  }, [])
  return isMounted
}

const SomeComponent = props => {
  const isMounted = useMounted()

  return isMounted
    ? <div>Mounted client-side component</div>
    : <SomeComponentSkeleton />
}
```

Effectively this just prevents issues with hydration that occur if you return `null` on server-side render and then return a component on the client-side. You can also use `isMounted` to kick off any code that uses `window` et al.